# How to get the summery-image URL in Orchard view override

Tags: orchardcms

I use `Orchard CMS 1.10.1`. I'm overriding View of a `summary display type` of a content type, for this, I need url of image field in display type summary.

I can get the image url itseft this way :

```
@Model.ContentItem.Product.Images.FirstMediaUrl
```

This is part of the view altenate:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src=@Model.ContentItem.Product.Images.FirstMediaUrl />
</div>
```

My question is how can I get url of summary of this image? So I can replace the above url  with the summary one.

Comment: What do you mean with ' url of summary of this image'? Orchard has one url for each media file, are you want resized url? or you want the summary display for image content item?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I want summary display for image content item

Comment: I dont use zones in this view just img tag and url of the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```html
@{
    var image = Model.ContentItem.Product.Images.MediaParts.First();
}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Display(BuildDisplay(image, "Summary"))
</div>
```

You need to display it like this because `Image` in Orchard is a content item, but if you want to display image url inline with resizing you can do the following:

```html
@{
    var imageUrl = Model.ContentItem.Product.Images.FirstMediaUrl;
}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="@Display.ResizeMediaUrl(Width: 200, Height: 200, Mode: "crop", Alignment: "middlecenter", Path: imageUrl)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Great, Thanks it worked for me. I just have a problem with placement.info, seems like view alternate cant see placement.info of current theme.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding using the URL, use the Placement.info to obtain the summary shape of the media item.

In your view override:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @Display(Model.ImageSummary)
</div>
```

And in your Placement.info

```
<Match ContentType="MyContentType">
    <!-- ImageSummary is the local zone name which you then can display with
         @Display(Model.ImageSummary) in Content-MyContentType.cshtml -->
    <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_Summary="ImageSummary:1" />
</Match>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did as u said, for some reason it doesn't show the image. And when I use shape tracing it doesn't have any placement.info file for this. Seems it wont recognize placement.info in the root of my current theme.

Comment: Can you include your placement.info in your question?

Comment: Its almost empty. just this <Placement> <Place Parts_Image_Summary="ImageSummary:1" /> </Placement>

Comment: seems like this alternate view cant see placement.info of my current theme

Comment: This will not work because you are dealing with 'MediaPickerField' not the image content item itself, if you want to continue with this solution, you should change the 'Parts_Image_Summary' to 'Fields_MediaLibraryPicker_Summary'

Comment: @mdameer you are correct :) changed the placement.info